# Opencart not working, when i change php.ini

Tags: php

My opencart 2.0 is not working properly. I've changed my custom php.ini in isp config. After changing the text, my openchart home page is succesfully loaded, but when i click on any of the categories, i get only a blank page, but my url is proper. display error is on, and the php script is ok. My php.ini is not original.
Can I restore ISP config? How? What php.ini is not workint properly?.
Please help me

[image: My current running php.ini]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is due to that the mod rewrite of Apache web server isn't supported. So, the url rewrite doesn't work.